# Get all the nodes until a different one with XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm using Xpath to analyse HTML nodes using PHP.

In a case similar as following :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h2>Something</h2>
        <p>Parag 1</p>
        <p>Parag 2</p>
        <span>Span 1</span>
        <p>Parag 3</p>
      <h2>Something</h2>
        <p>Parag 1</p>
        <p>Parag 2</p
      <h2>Something</h2>
        <p>Parag 1</p>
        <p>Parag 2</p>
        <span>Span 1</span>
        <p>Parag 3</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use a loop to browse those nodes but I have an issue to only get nodes beetween titles.
Actually I want to separate the content between each h2.

I tried something like :

```
//h2/following-sibling::*[1 = count(preceding-sibling::h3[1])]
```

But that doesn't work well.

Does someone has an idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Jap

### EDIT

Sorry my example wasn't clear. I try to explain my issue better.

I'm scrapping a web page where tags don't have same identification class.

```
$html = '<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <article id="article1">
        <h2 class="about">Title 1</h2>
          <p>Parag 1.1</p>
          <p>Parag 1.2</p>
          <span>Span 1.1</span>
          <p>Parag 1.3</p>
        <h2 class="ideas">Title 2</h2>
          <p>Parag 1.4</p>
          <p>Parag 1.5</p
        <h2 class="final">Title 3</h2>
          <p>Parag 1.6</p>
          <span>Span 1.2</span>
          <p>Parag 1.7</p>
      </article>
      <article id="article2">
        <h2 class="previously">Title 1</h2>
          <p>Parag 2.1</p>
        <h2 class="about">Title 2</h2>
          <p>Parag 2.2</p>
          <span>Span 2.1</span>
          <p>Parag 2.3</p>
        <h2 class="final">Title 3</h2>
          <p>Parag 2.4</p>
          <span>Span 2.2</span>
      </article>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>'
```

For each article (which are within the same page) I only want to get nodes after the h2 tag with the class "about" until the next h2 tag whatever its class or content.

To do so, I use a PHP script :

In the following script $expression is the xpath expression I need :

```
$expression = "./h2[.,'Title 1']/following-sibling::*[1 = count(preceding-sibling::h2[1])]";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$main = $xpath->query("//div/article");

foreach ($main as $article) {
    
    echo $xpath->query($expression, $article)->nodeValue;
    echo "<br />";

}
```

The purpose is by using the loop only to display the tags from one h2 tag until the next one.

In my example, I want to get the tags : Parag 1.1 / Parag 1.2 / Span 1.1 / Parag 1.3 / Parag 2.2 / Span 2.1 / Parag 2.3

In article 1 :

```
<p>Parag 1.1</p>
<p>Parag 1.2</p>
<span>Span 1.1</span>
<p>Parag 1.3</p>
```

And also in article 2 :

```
<p>Parag 2.2</p>
<span>Span 2.1</span>
<p>Parag 2.3</p>
```

I hope it's much clear.

Thanks

Comment: Where is `h3` in your html ? and also your requirement isn't clear. Please reorganize your question.

Comment: please change example html: for example make all tag texts unique and then say what tag you want to find by xpath

Comment: I edited the post to provide a best example

Answer (score 2):

**For this markup,**

```
<html> 
  <body> 
    <div> 
      <h2>A</h2>  
      <p>1</p>  
      <p>2</p>  
      <span>3</span>  
      <p>4</p>  

      <h2>B</h2>  
      <p>5</p>  
      <p>6</p>  

      <h2>C</h2>  
      <p>7</p>  
      <p>8</p>  
      <span>9</span>  
      <p>10</p> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

**this XPath,**

```
//*[preceding-sibling::h2 = 'B' and following-sibling::h2 = 'C']
```

**will select the markup between the `"B"` and `"C"` headings,**

```
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
```

**as requested (if I'm guessing correctly -- problem statement was unclear).**